# WebForms with ASP.NET AJAX: HyperLink vs LinkButton & Response.Redirect from GridView

Tags: asp.net, caching, webforms, asp.net-ajax, http-headers

I have 2 asp.net web forms. The first has a ScriptManager, History, UpdatePanel and GridView; the later is ScriptManager, UpdatePanel and TextBoxes. The premise here is a list that links to a detail form where an item can be edited.

From within the GridView (inside the UpdatePanel), if I use a HyperLink control with the url set to the edit page (with the necessary parameters), change something, save it and then click the back button I see the original list with no updates. Pressing F5 to refresh shows the changes.

If instead I use a LinkButton inside the GridView, and handle that LinkButton in code-behind to perform a Response.Redirect to the same edit page (with the same parameters), make the same changes, save and then click the back button, the list on the original page refreshes automatically to show my changes.

Note that the code in the detail page where the editing/saving takes place does not change - only the way it is first displayed is changed.

My question is this: what is it about the Response.Redirect that causes the page to be refreshed when the back button is clicked, and it it possible to replicate this for the direct HyperLink approach? I would prefer to use the HyperLink method as I see no reason for the postback, but I want the GridView to refresh when the user browses back to it.

Thanks.

Comment: I added http-headers and caching tags so maybe we'll get some experts on the subject in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LinkButton causes a postback, the response to which is a HTTP 302 redirect command triggered on the server side by your Response.Redirect.  Your web browser therefore does not cache the old version of the page.

The Hyperlink control simply renders a regular `<a>` tag which takes you to the detail page on the client side.  The browser has no reason to believe the page may have changed, so it presents the cached version when you hit the back button.

If you want to tell the browser specifically not to cache the page if the back button is used, 
 use the cache-control HTTP header.  [W3C Link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1),

In any case, you should provide a link on the detail page (or automatic redirect on accepting changes) which takes the user back to the GridView/summary page, so they don't have to resort to using the back button.

**Edit:**

Sorry, the previously provided header example was not for Asp.net, but basically you'll want to do something like this:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
```

Comment: I have looked at providing links to return the list in the past; it all gets very messy very quickly when the users insist on being able to use the back button too. There is also the problem of paging etc. Your explanation however was fantastic - thanks.

Comment: @MartinRobins  I added some detail about how to use the cache-control HTTP header to enable to use Hyperlink controls with the desired effect.  Let me know if it works out.

Comment: I have tried various combinations of the caching parameters (now including my interpretation of your "Wicket" example - Response.Headers.Add(@"Cache-Control", @"no-cache, max-age=0,must-revalidate, no-store");) and all to no avail. The closest I got was the browser telling me that the page had expired and had to be refreshed!

Comment: @MartinRobins Yeah, sorry about that.  I just tested out the above code in my edit and it appears to work as intended (no error message, just a forced refresh).  Maybe the UpdatePanel is causing issues?